# How to write test case for Spring boot controller using spock framework

Tags: java, spring-boot, groovy, spock

I have written a simple rest application using Spring boot, now I want to write a unit test case for my controllers using the Spock framework. I already tried like this
, but it did not Succeed

My controller class

```
 public class AbcController extends BaseController{
    
        private final AbcService abcService;
    
        public UserController(AbcService abcService) {
            this.abcService= abcService;
        }
         @GetMapping("/all")
        public ResponseEntity<List<AbcDto>> getAll(@RequestHeader(name = "Authorization") 
         String accessToken) {
         
            return getResponseEntity (abcService.getAll(accessToken));
        }
    
        }
```

Service

```
 public class AbcServiceImpl implementsAbcService {
    public List<AbcDto> getAll(String accessKey) {
            try {
               
                List<AbcDto> abc= AbcServiceClient.getAll (accessKey);
              
                return users;
            } catch (FeignException exception) {
                
                throw exception;
            }
        }
    }
```

My test case

```
class AbcControllerSpecification extends Specification{

    def "Should test getAll"() {


        given: "mock service"
        AbcDto abc= new AbcDto(null, "cm@gmail.com", true, true, null);
        List<AbcDto> response = Arrays.asList(abc)
       AbcController controller
        ResponseEntity response
        controller = new AbcController(abcService: service)
        AbcUserServiceClient abcServiceClient = Mock() {
            getUAll("bearer") >> response
        }
        AbcServiceImpl abcService = new AbcServiceImpl(abcServiceClient);



        when: "call abcService getAll"
        response = controller.getAll(abcServiceClient);

        then:"return all List"
        result == response
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you post pseudo code? Where does `service` come from? And why is `abcService`, seemingly serving the same purpose as `service`, defined _after_ you probably want to inject it into your controller? Maybe you want to get your example code in order, ideally reproducing your issue, also adding now missing dependencies like the DTO source code. Please also describe the expected result for your test and how the actual result differs. If there are any error messages, please post them, too. "It did not succeed" does not qualify as a helpful error description. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the examples ([WebMVC](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/master/spock-spring/boot2-test/src/test/groovy/org/spockframework/boot2/WebMvcTestIntegrationSpec.groovy), [SpringBean](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/master/spock-spring/src/test/groovy/org/spockframework/spring/mock/SpringBeanSpec.groovy)) in the Spock repository. Also make sure that you have a dependency on the `spock-spring` module in addition to the `spock-core` dependency.

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class HelloWorldService {

    @Value("${name:World}")
    private String name;

    public String getHelloMessage() {
        return "Hello " + this.name;
    }

}
```

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
public class HelloWorldController {

  private HelloWorldService service;

  @Autowired
  public HelloWorldController(HelloWorldService service) {
    this.service = service;
  }

  @RequestMapping("/")
  public String hello() {
    return service.getHelloMessage();
  }

}
```

```
import spock.lang.Specification

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status

@WebMvcTest
class WebMvcTestIntegrationSpec extends Specification {

  @Autowired
  MockMvc mvc

  @SpringBean
  HelloWorldService helloWorldService = Stub()

  def "spring context loads for web mvc slice"() {
    given:
    helloWorldService.getHelloMessage() >> 'hello world'

    expect: "controller is available"
    mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/"))
      .andExpect(status().isOk())
      .andExpect(content().string("hello world"))
  }
}
```